# Prevent Excel file from remember old DLL data. DLL Hell?

Tags: c, excel, vba, dll

I've made simlpe C DLL:

```
void msgbox(long n)
{
    char tmp[255];
    sprintf(tmp, "%ld", n);
    MessageBoxA(0, tmp, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
void DLL_EXPORT showMessageBoxWithLong(long n1)
{
    msgbox(n1);
}
```

and it works:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function showMessageBoxWithLong Lib "MyExcelDLL.dll" (ByVal n1 As Long) As Long

Sub testDLL()
    showMessageBoxWithLong 3
End Sub
```

But after little change (made with FreeLibrary, overwrite DLL and LoadLibrary again)

```
void DLL_EXPORT showMessageBoxWithLong(long n1, long n2)
{
    msgbox(n1);
    msgbox(n2);
}
```

it doesn't (shows first argument ok, and trash instead of second argument):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function showMessageBoxWithLong Lib "MyExcelDLL.dll" (ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long) As Long

Sub testDLL()
    showMessageBoxWithLong 3, 7
End Sub
```

until I change name of function or I use it in any other workbook. With any other name it works. That makes me think that there is some place in xlsm file where Excel stores somethink like "this function from this DLL needs one argument" and never updates that info.

Comment: As far as I know, any COM DLL that can be used with VBA needs to be registered in Windows. There are no details on that point in the Question, but my first trouble-shooting step would be to check in the Registry which and how these are registered and then check the Tools/References of the VBA project which of these (or if both) are being used. My best guess would be that the Reference to the first attempt needs to be removed...

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm using LoadLibrary() from kernel32. I can't register that DLL because I can't use administrator account.

Comment: What about version number then? If you increase it, does that have the wanted effect?

Comment: OK... Next "stupid question": Are both procedures still in the DLL? Because VBA does not recognize "overloading" with different parameters - it can't differentiate on the basis of one function having one and the other two parameters. The function names have to be different. VBA, itself, uses *optional* parameters, instead.

Comment: @CindyMeister No. There is only one. I've editted original function to take two parameteres. (I'm using pure C to prevent names mangling and other problems like that)

Comment: @Sam I've tried increase version number in *.rc file. Nothing changed.